# Calculating probability

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

If $f(x,y)=2x , 0\leq x\leq 1 ,0\leq y\leq 1 $, find $ P(Y < e^{-X} \cap X > Y)$ Given X and Y have joint distribution.
Here is my approach:
$$ P(Y < e^{-X} \cap X > Y) =  1-  P(Y > e^{-X} \cap X > Y)$$
= $1- P(X > Y > e^{-X})$ = $P(e^{-X} \leq Y \leq X )$
=$ \int_0^1\int_{e^{-x}}^x2x dydx $
=  $2e^{-1} - \frac{1}{3}$

Is my solution for this problem correct?
Thanks!

Comment: (1) Presumably $f$ is a bivariate probability density function. (2) The question asks for a probability, which (by definition) is a *number.* The answer you propose depends on some undefined variable "$x$": this makes no sense. (3) The answer is fairly nasty: it will help to write it in terms of the number $x$ satisfying $x = \exp(-x)$. If this is a probability homework problem, it seems to miss the pedagogical mark by requiring the evaluation of such an integral. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: @whuber I missed to mention that X & Y are jointly distributed, which I corrected in the question now.

Comment: That was implied by introducing $f$, assuming it is the PDF of the joint distribution.

Comment: @whuber I think what I missed in my solution is that I need to double integrate it wrt to x and y. But I am not understanding why I need to do it, is it because it is bivariate.

Comment: This would seem to fall under [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Please review the tag wiki info and add the tag (or if it doesn't apply, would you mind explaining how the question arises, please). There's no difficulty though - you seem to be following what it asks for in any case.

Comment: It is still unclear what "$x$" is: in "$P(Y\lt e^{-x}\ldots)$" is it a typo for "$X$" or is $x$ some constant independent of the random variables $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @whuber & Glen_b I have updated the question and also my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *event* for a bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ is any set of possible outcomes to which a probability can meaningfully be assigned.  Examples are the set of outcomes $(x,y)$ such that $y\lt e^{-x},$ the set for which $x\gt y,$ and their intersection (about which the question is concerned).

**The probability of any event is the volume under the graph of $f$ subtending that event.**  We can draw a picture of this probability:

[image: Figure]

The open (dark yellow) chamber is bounded at the bottom by $y=0$, on the right by $x=1$, on the upper right by $y=e^{-x}$, on the upper left by $y=x$, and above by the graph of $f$.  The rest of the graph of $f$ is shown in dark blue with a mesh.

The calculation of this volume can be carried out in two parts: first, the integral over $x=0$ to $x=x_0$ where $(x_0, x_0) = (x_0, e^{-x_0})$ is the point at which the two graphs $y=x$ and $y=e^{-x}$ intersect.  ($x_0\approx 0.567$.)

[image: First region]

Second, the integral from $x=x_0$ to $x=1$.

[image: Second region]

The probability is

$$\int_0^{x_0} \int_0^x 2x\ dy dx + \int_{x_0}^1\int_0^{e^{-x}} 2x\ dy dx$$

$$= 2\frac{x_0^3}{3} + 2\left(\frac{2}{e} + x_0 + x_0^2\right)$$

$$\approx 0.427687.$$

Notice this differs from $2/e - 1/3\approx 0.402426.$

---

With problems like this it can be helpful (and often insightful) to double-check one's answer with a simulation.  This requires us to write code to draw values of $(X,Y)$ from the specified distribution.  In this case, notice that $Y$ has a uniform distribution *independent* of $X$ and that the distribution function of $X$ (for $0\le x \le 1)$

$$F_X(x) = \int_{0}^x\int_{0}^{1} f(t,y)\ dy dt = x^2.$$

Therefore, since the inverse of $F_X$ is the square root (restricted to arguments between $0$ and $1$), $X$ is distributed as the *square root* of a uniform distribution.

The following `R` code generates ten million independent realizations of $(X,Y)$.  It estimates the desired probability as the fraction of realizations in which the event occurs.  It also computes its standard error:

```r
n<- 10^7                  # Number of realizations
set.seed(17)              # Allows this calculation to be reproduced
x <- sqrt(runif(n))       # The X values
y <- runif(n)             # The Y values
i <- y < exp(-x) & x > y  # Indicator of the event
mean(i)                   # Estimated probability
sd(i) / sqrt(length(i))   # Standard error of the estimate
```

After $1.7$ seconds of computation, this simulation yields a probability estimate of $0.42769$ with a standard error of $0.00016$.

(This simulation could be made several times faster, but it does the job in reasonable time and has the merit of being such a direct translation of the original question that it evidently is *correct* code.)

**Doing this simulation would have cast strong doubt on the validity of $0.4024$ as an answer**, because that is $160$ standard errors too low (and more than three SEs would be suspicious).  Indeed, even $0.4291$ is suspicious because it is $9$ SEs higher than the estimate.  In contrast, the answer developed here ($0.427687$) differs from the estimate by only $0.03$ standard errors: it is bang on.

Comment: Significantly better than the answer I was just working on.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the beautiful explanation. I just finished the problem and saw the answer posted by you. I took the similar approach by drawing it in 2 dimensional plane and looking for regions for range of x and y. I am now able to see that earlier solution was wrong as I missed the fact that the region involves two curves. My answer, with correct approach, is 0.4291 (which is close to yours).